# convert nextSibling to Input

Tags: javascript

i've a table with cells in which i can enter values (the table is a timetable and i can enter the room number inside the cell by make a double click on this cell).
Now i want to add a key listener on the tab-key.
if i press the tab-key, the value in the current cell should get saved and the next cell (right to the current cell) converts to a input-field. but if i press the tab-key the value gets save (as i want) and the next cell converts to a input field (as i want) but just stay there for a milisecond and then it disappears and i dont know why

For more code please ask

Here is the code:

```
 //the cell which get double-clicked
function toInput(cell){
                var input = document.createElement('input');
                input.value = cell.innerHTML;
                setTimeout(function() { input.focus(); }, 200);
                cell.appendChild(input);
                alert("toInput");

                window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
                    if(e.keyCode == '13'){
                        var text = input.value;
                        cell.innerHTML = text;
                        //the function which send the data to the backend 
                        getData("get"+getString(cell.parentNode.cells[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML));
                    }else if(e.keyCode == '9'){
                        alert("tab");
                        var text = input.value;
                        cell.innerHTML = text;
                        getData("get"+getString(cell.parentNode.cells[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML));
                        toInput(cell.nextSibling);

                    }
                }, false);

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the getData-function, which is an ajax-call is finished and built up the table after the toInput-function gets called. So a input-field gets added and the old-table (before the input field gets added) rebuilt again.

```
function toInput(cell){
                    var input = document.createElement('input');
                    input.value = cell.innerHTML;
                    setTimeout(function() { input.focus(); }, 200);
                    cell.appendChild(input);

                    window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
                        if(e.keyCode == '13'){
                            var text = input.value;
                            cell.innerHTML = text;
                            getData("get"+getString(cell.parentNode.cells[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML));
                        }else if(e.keyCode == '9'){
                            var text = input.value;
                            cell.innerHTML = text;
                            //getData("get"+getString(cell.parentNode.cells[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML)); 
                            toInput(cell.nextSibling);
                        }
                    }, true);

                }
```

Answer (score 1):

There were a few issues with your code. This one should fix it. I added a lots of comments. Feel free to ask if anything is unclear.

```
function toInput(cell){

    // use let (limits the scope of the variable to current function)
    let input = document.createElement('input');

    // read content and place it in your input
    input.value = cell.innerHTML;

    // clear HTML content of cell, now that we read its value
    cell.innerHTML = '';

    // append input in empty cell
    cell.appendChild(input);


    // focus on input which exists
    input.focus();


    // add a listener on this input
    input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){


        // ENTER key or TAB key (common code)
        if(e.keyCode == '13' || e.keyCode == '9'){


            // remove current element + its handlers and update cell value
            cell.innerHTML = input.value;


            // the function which send the data to the backend 
            // the last function is a callback function (executes at the end of something asynchronous, like AJAX)
            getData("get"+getString(cell.parentNode.cells[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML), function(){

                // only for TAB key, convert next CELL to INPUT
                if(e.keyCode == '9'){
                    toInput(cell.nextSibling);
                }

            });
        }

    }, false);
}

function getData(your_parameter, callback){

     // your code ...
     // inside ajax success loop, at the end add this:

     if (typeof callback == 'function'){
        // if the callback parameter is a function, execute it
        callback();
     }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that the getData-function (ajax-request) is finished after the toInput-function

Comment: @DoFlamingo I have updated the answer accordingly. You need to make use of a callback function inside getData(). Read a little bit about callbacks here: https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced

Comment: why the cell.classList?

Comment: @DoFlamingo I did something with it earlier, then forgot to delete the line from code. I removed it now. Thanks for pointing it out. :)